# Notification under Loop swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying to generate notification under for-loop. When I run my loop with notification method inside it, it fires only the last one. My identifier is different for each time. "WillPresent Notification" method calls for the last value and when I match the identifier, it fails. Can anyone please tell me what to do ?

```
func triggerNotification(){

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Your device found a new beacon"
    content.subtitle = "Press to open"
    content.body = "Sample code from WWDC"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    //To Present image in notification
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "monkey", ofType: "png") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "sampleImage", url: url, options: nil)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        } catch {
            //                print("attachment not found.")
        }
    }

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.001, repeats: false)
    print("requestCountValueOld", requestCountValue)
    requestCountValue += 1
    print("requestCountValueNew", requestCountValue)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: String(requestCountValue), content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Show the for loop.

Comment: can you try to schedule the notifications with some delay 1 second for example timeInterval: 1.

Comment: for _ in 0...10 {
            triggerNotification()
        }

Comment: try doing it a few seconds apart, you may be sending too many notifications that are set to be shown at pretty much the same time, so therefore being throttled

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion guys. It helped me and I sorted out my issue

Answer (score 0):

When you use `init(timeInterval:repeats:)` of UNNotificationRequest timeInterval parameter should be greater than 0.  This is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger/1649777-init)

> The time (in seconds) that must elapse from the current time before
>   the trigger fires. This value must be greater than zero.

As you can see this is the time in seconds. First I think that you should pass more than 1 second in order to work. But I think this is not true you can add less than this and the problem that you have is in some small detail.

If you continue digging, timeInterval converts to milliseconds which means 0.001 from seconds are 1 millisecond. But here is the problem sometimes 0.001 can be 0.00999999 which is less than 1 millisecond and it can become as 0 and this is a problem with what you have in the documentation.

You should be fine if you change your code:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.001, repeats: false)
```

with

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @m1sh0. It helped me and I sorted out my issue.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma When an answer solves your issue you should indicate that you question is resolved by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the best answer.